# Is it possible to pass additional attributes to a Sentry user feedback report?

Tags: sentry

I would like to pass an additional parameter like **keepMeInformed** on *Sentry Report feedback*. Their embed report feedback form supports only:
 - comments
 - email
 - name
I can create my own `Report feedback` dialog with Rest API usage on submit. But i can't find any way to bind this **keepMeInformed** as tag or extra value to existing event.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into details as to which SDK you're using I can't help you with an exact answer, but if your SDK has a `beforeSend` callback you could use that to both 1) delay the event going out until the user has decided on whether they would want to get informed 2) set a tag value based on that.

Comment: Hi Markus Unterwaditzer!
I am using @sentry/browser v5.14.2 with react app. Our flow is the next:  
1. User press the **Report Feedback** button  
2. Check the tick on **Keep me informed**. 
3. Press the **Submit**. 

-----back-end side------  
4. once sentry issue has been resolved, web hook is triggered.  
5. end point for that trigger process sentry event and check the **keepMeInformed** flag if so then we send email template to user about the solving issue